# Is it possible to auto initialize a date field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I would like to auto initialize a date field (without the time), and then auto initialize a time field (without the date) in 2 separate columns (I don't want them in the same column)...

Is this possible?

I thought this would work... but it doesn't.

```
CREATE TABLE `account_ip_history` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(39) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_time` time NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) is quite clear:

> `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns can be automatically initializated and
>   updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp).

If `DATE` could be initialized it would be included in the documentation.

So, simply do:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_ip_history` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(39) NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` datetim NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can extract the `date` and `time` components when you query the table.

Comment: This would not work, because I wanted to make the date field and ip_address field a unique index... and then use an INSERT or UPDATE query to ONLY add new records once a day. But it does answer my question of is it possible to auto assign date and time... so thanks.